# Get the word right before the coma with javascript and regex?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, input, words

Hi im trying to get the word right before the coma in a sentence.

For example if the string is:

```
"Cloudy, and 51 ° F "
```

I want the output CLOUDY.

How is this done in regex and javascript? I know you have to use the .match command in javascript. Thanks, any help is appricated.

Comment: In the first case, Cloudy is not the second word ?

Comment: String output = checkString.Contains("Mostly") ? checkString.Replace("Mostly","") : checkString; Then just split into array and grab the first element in array.

Comment: "(depending on the case)" Depending how?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard Thats what I meant by depending on the case. The input is varied. Sometimes cloudy is first and sometime its first. Sometimes the word might not even be cloudy. I want to check if the string contains the word mostly, and if it does get the second word. Else get the first word. If thats not too confusing. ;)

Comment: I'm still confused.  So, you're looking for the word *Cloudy* and if it doesn't appear, always return the second word?

Comment: `str.split(',')[0].split(' ').pop()` in case you need a word before the first comma :)

Comment: What shall be the output of **Sometimes a bit Cloudy, but mostly sunshine**?

Comment: No if _mostly_ appears return the second word (cloudy in this case). Else return the first word (So if mostly is not in the sentence. Cloudy is the first word). I could use Replace("Mostly","") to get rid of _Mostly_ then just match to the first word.

Comment: +YuryTarabanko That's what I needed! I just noticed that the word I need is the one right before the comma in both case! How can I get this Word??

Comment: `var aWord = str.split(',')[0].split(' ').pop()` like this.

Comment: Removing my close vote in case @YuryTarabanko wants to post an answer.

Comment: Yup @YuryTarabanko solved it. The split always returns the word right before the comma. Thanks everyone and sorry for the confusion. If anyone wants this post deleted let me know.

Comment: @SunnyD - Instead, I would edit the post to make it more clear.  Take what you've explained in the comments and add it to the post.

Comment: @MikeChristensen Done! Would you say that is clear enough?

Comment: @SunnyD - I'd add another example or two.  Such as "Mostly Cloudy," and "Mostly Sunny," and "Rainy," along with which word it should return.  But overall I think it's clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wanted to add an alternative to the `split` solution in the comments.

Here's the simplest regex you can use:

```
\S+(?=,)
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/gS3uA3/1). In regex syntax, it *literally* means *sequence of non-whitespace characters followed by a comma*.

Here's how to use this from JS:

```
var str = "Mostly cloudy, and 51 ° F";
var matches = str.match(/\S+(?=,)/g); // matches = ["cloudy"]
```

`matches` will contain an array with all the words followed by a comma in `str`. If you only need the first match, remove the `g`.

Comment: it's better to use `\S+` instead of `\w+`

Comment: @AvinashRaj Yes, that's better for non-English input strings and for words with dashes. I'll update the answer, thanks.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Btw, why did you mark this question as a duplicate of an unrelated question?

Comment: you could get the answer also from capturing groups .